# Email SMTP (liberação de porta)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer, smtp

Eu to tentando enviar um email pelo phpmailer, mas sempre dá erro. Aí fui olhar uns exemplos do git, mas nem os exemplos estão indo. Eu preciso liberar a porta 25 ou 465 para conseguir enviar o email SMTP?

Comment: Qual erro dá? Erro de conexão? Habilite o debug para ver o que acontece. $mail->SMTPDebug = true; Geralmente utilizo a porta 587 para meus trabalhos com PHPMailer. $mail->Port = 587;

Comment: Eu preciso mudar minha porta no xampp pra 587 para conseguir fazer isso?

Comment: Ele dá o seguinte erro: 
Erro no envio do e-mailSMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
E eu já pesquisei e fiz tudo que mandam, mas até o exemplo do github nao vai, fica dando falha tambem

Comment: Se dá simplesmente SMTP connect() failed, é por que em algum motivo a conexão foi recusada. As vezes não é porta. Veja se seu servidor não pede autenticação SMTP, login, senha... você colocou o Debug que eu informei? Geralmente nele tem mais dados sobre o erro.

Comment: Qual servidor SMTP você está tentando conectar?? se for do gmail você precisa configurar também o `SMTPSecure` para `ssl`. Se for outro, precisa ver o que é necessário para configuração. Qualquer informação que faltar, poderá dar falha. Aqui você tem um exemplo do PHPMailer com gmail: https://www.gn10.com.br/blog/dicas/envie-emails-php-smtp-gmail-google-apps/  Ligue também o `SMTPDebug = 1;` colocando em 1, para exibir mensagens de erro. Assim você poderá ter mais detalhes do que está acontecendo.